# Certain Apps Do Not Work on Cellular Data

Tags: mobile-data, t-mobile

Some apps (Outlook, Gmail, Life360) **do not function on cellular data, but function perfectly on WiFi**. I've already checked for unlimited cell data, resetting APNs, reinstalling the apps, factory resetting and installing only those apps... I uninstalled Family Link as well after reading about that on a Google forum. I also saw the "google apps lose connection..." article, but its steps don't help. Needless to say, everything is updated.

Other apps, like Google Search, NHL, etc. work fine on cell. However, some websites like discord.com give certificate errors when loading.

When I say Outlook doesn't work, here is more detail about its symptoms: Message notifications appear, but the messages don't load. Outlook says "no connection." Similar issues with Gmail. Life360 can't load locations/sync at all, either. Trying to set up Outlook on just cell leads towards this article (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/adal-authenticate-android-devices-fail), but I can't verify that this is indeed the problem (I have am not redirected to a federated STS login page.)

The phone is a T-Mobile Revvl V+ 5G running up-to-date Android 11. Other iPhone devices on the same T-Mobile plan work fine, so this appears to be a T-Mobile/Android/device problem, especially as the problem is with many (but confoundingly, not all) apps.

Note: the issue appears both with WiFi enabled, but unavailable, and with WiFi off.

This is most irritating, as if I needed a WiFi device, I would use a laptop. Any help is *extremely* appreciated!

Comment: Since how long do you have these problems (hours, days, weeks)?

Comment: It's happened as long as the phone has existed, sadly, apart from a few hours after the first time I set it up. (I made no network/wifi/app settings changes in that time)